# Run application as root by default

Tags: permissions, launcher, root

I have just installed WebStorm on my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04. The project I am working on uses `git`. If I run WebStorm from Launcher I cannot do a lot of things that need `root` permissions (of course). I want to be able to do something easier than opening a Terminal and typing `sudo wstorm` and then entering my password.

I tried creating a `.sh` file, but I don't know how to (1) bypass my password and (2) make it available from Launcher. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean with "do a lot of things that need root permissions"

Comment: For example, working with `git`. But why does it matter? I want to run it as `root` without entering the password every time and nothing more.

Comment: Why should `git` need root permissions?

Comment: And the same for WebStorm? Why root?

Comment: Git needs permissions for `index.lock` or something like that. @A.B., I suppose you downvoted, but I don't understand why. It is a thing I want to do on my Ubuntu system and asked it on an Ubuntu Q&A website. So I don't see any reason...

Comment: git does not need root permissions unless you cloned something with sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new script file (replace create_dir.sh with your desired script name):

```
vim ~/create_dir.sh
```

The script will be created in the user’s home directory

Add some commands that only a root or sudo user can execute like creating a folder at the root directory level:

```
mkdir /abc
```

Note: Don’t add sudo to these commands. Save and exit (using :wq!)

Assign execute permissions to it using:

```
sudo chmod u+x create_dir.sh
```

Make changes so that this script doesn’t require a password.

- Open the sudoers file:

  ```
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
  ```
- Add the following line at the end:

  ```
  ahmad ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/ahmad/create_dir.sh
  ```

  Replace  **ahmad**   with whatever your username is. Also make sure this is the last line. Save and exit.

  Now when running the command add sudo before it like:

  ```
  sudo ./create_dir.sh
  ```

  This will run the commands inside the script file without asking for a password.

This is not mine reference [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

Comment: The problem with this is that disabling the `sudo` password is a big security risk. Sure it won't ask for a password for the app, but it also won't ask for a password for say `sudo rm -R /`

Comment: @Zacharee1 who disables `sudo` for, eg, `rm`?

Comment: @A.B. what do you mean?